# Abstract Interpretation: prove that the sign subtraction is increasing in each of its parameters

Tags: formal-methods, static-analysis

I need to prove that the binary operator $-_\pm: \mathbb{P}^\pm\times\mathbb{P}^\pm\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^\pm$ is increasing in each of its arguments, where

$$
  \mathbb{P}^\pm = \{\top_\pm, \leq0,\neq0, \geq0,<0,=0,>0,\bot_\pm\}
$$

are the abstract properties it operates on. They represent the "signs" of values in $\mathbb Z$.

Their concretizations are, resp.,

$$
  \mathcal{P}^\pm = \{
    \mathbb Z,
    \{z \in \mathbb Z \mid z \leq0\},
    \{z \in \mathbb Z \mid z \neq0\},
    \{z \in \mathbb Z \mid z \geq0\}, \ldots,
    \emptyset
  \}
$$

The concretization of a sign property $s$ is given by $\gamma(s)$, where $\gamma$ is an isomorphism between the posets $(\mathcal{P}^\pm, \subseteq)$ and $(\mathbb{P}^\pm, \sqsubseteq)$, and

$$
  \forall s_1,s_2\in\mathbb{P}^\pm . s_1 \sqsubseteq s_2 \iff \gamma(s_1)\subseteq\gamma(s_2).
$$

I couldn't find any smart way to prove the monotonicity of $-_\pm$, so I just built an $8\times8$ "subtraction table" with $s_1-_\pm s_2$ for every possible pair of signs. For each valid $i$, let $r_i$ be the $i$-th row, and $s_i$ the property associated with $r_i$. I simply verified that if $s_i \sqsubseteq s_j$ then, for all valid $k$, $r_{ik}\sqsubseteq r_{jk}$. I did the same for the columns.

This is quite bruteforc-y, although it didn't take long thanks to the table. I'd just like to know whether this is the correct way to solve this exercise or not.

Comment: [Abstract Interpretation](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/512950.512973) is a formal method for statically analyzing the behavior of programs. My question is about an exercise from the book "Principles of Abstract Interpretation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $P$ is a property, let $\alpha(P)$ be its best sound abstraction. *"Sound"* means that $P\subseteq \gamma(\alpha(P))$, that is, $\alpha(P)$ *overapproximates* $P$. *"Best"* means that if $p$ is another sound abstraction of $P$, then $\alpha(P)\sqsubseteq p$, that is, $\gamma(\alpha(P))\subseteq \gamma(p)$, that is, $\alpha(P)$ is more *precise*.

The operator $-_\pm$ was naturally defined such that it's optimal w.r.t. the abstract properties, that is

$$
  s_1 -_\pm s_2 = \alpha_\pm (\{x-y \mid x\in \gamma_\pm(s_1) \wedge y\in \gamma_\pm(s_2)\})
$$

For instance:

\begin{align}
  (>0) -_\pm (<0) &= \alpha_\pm(\{x \mid x>0\} -^* \{y \mid y<0\}) \\
     &= \alpha_\pm(\{x \mid x>0\} +^* \{y \mid y>0\}) \\
     &= \alpha_\pm(\{x \mid x>0\}) \\
     &= (>0)
\end{align}

where I introduced the two star operators for convenience. (I leave the trivial definition to the reader.)

Let's define $f$ as follows:

$$
  f(s, t) = \{x-y \mid x\in \gamma_\pm(s) \wedge y\in \gamma_\pm(t)\}
$$

Note that $s_1\ -_\pm s_2 = \alpha_\pm(f(s_1, s_2))$.

It's now easy to see that, for all valid $s_2$:

\begin{align}
    s_1 \sqsubseteq s_1' &\implies \gamma_\pm(s_1) \subseteq \gamma_\pm (s_1') \\
       &\implies f(s_1, s_2) \subseteq f(s_1', s_2) \\
       &\implies s_1 -_\pm s_2 \sqsubseteq s_1' -_\pm s_2
\end{align}

The last implication follows from the fact that $\alpha$ is also increasing. Indeed, for every properties $P$ and $Q$ such that $P \subseteq Q$, we must have $P \subseteq Q \subseteq \gamma(\alpha(Q))$, which means that $\alpha(Q)$ is also a *sound* abstraction for $P$. For the optimality of $\alpha$, we must thus have $\alpha(P) \sqsubseteq \alpha(Q)$, which proves the monotonicity.

We can reason analogously for $s_2$, which concludes the proof.